# Count each numbers separately with regex?

Tags: regex, perl, int

My code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = <>;
chomp(@list);
my @matches =grep /^\d+(,\d+)*$/, @list;
if (@matches>0)
{
    print scalar @matches . "\n";
}
else {

}
```

And the input is this:

```
sd 45
gdfg 34
fg dfg 345 df
```

Then it should print `7`
But it prints `3`
How should I change the regex to count the integers separately?

Comment: Re "*But it prints `3`*", No, it prints nothing because there are no matching lines

Answer (score 0):

You've explained in the comments that you are asking how to extract the digits from your input.

```
my @digits;
while (my $line = <>) {
   push @digits, $line =~ /\d/g;
}
```

It can be surmised from your question that you also want to count them. That's just a question of evaluating the array in scalar context.

```
my $num_digits = @digits;
say "There are $num_digits digits: @digits";
```

Comment: Yes, but I want it separately
For example: 345 -> 3 4 5.
And I dont know how to do this.

Comment: @MTn, huh? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: The regex what I attached in the question counts "345" only as one number.

But because there is actually 3 separate number in it "3" "4" "5", I want it to be counted as three number.
 
So the print would be "3". 

Not "1".

Comment: Re "*The regex what I attached in the question counts "345" only as one number*", No it doesn't. It doesn't count anything at all. Regex patterns define a set of strings, and a regex match check if a string is part of the defined set of strings.

Comment: Re "*But because there is actually 3 separate number in it "3" "4" "5", I want it to be counted as three number*", The string `345` has three *digits*. Are you asking how how to count the number of digits in your input?

Comment: Well, then actually yes, but with list, if possible.

Comment: huh? I can't get a sensible sentence by adding "with list" to "how to count the number of digits in your input", no matter where I add it.

Comment: @ikegami I'm guessing they mean they want to capture them in the array, not just count them

Comment: Adjusted answer.

Answer (score 0):

To capture all the digits, as individual elements, you would do:

```
my @matches = map /([0-9])/, @list;
```

If you want to only capture digits for lines that are entirely digits, you would add a grep:

```
my @matches = map /([0-9])/, grep /^[0-9]+\z/, @list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read whole file into variable, use regex to extract separately each digit into an array.

Then output number of digits with `scalar @digits` and if you want to see list of the digits then `join ', ', @digits` will assist to get list of digits in easy to understand form.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $file = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my @digits = $file =~ /(\d)/g;

say 'Counted ' . scalar @digits . ' digits';
say 'List: ' . join ', ', @digits;

__DATA__
sd 45
gdfg 34
fg dfg 345 df
```

Output

```
Counted 7 digits
List: 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5
```